# Android setText always crash

Tags: android, textview

I'm using Android Studio to Create a Default Navigation Drawer Activity.
And I just do "setText", my app always crashed.

Here is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t1.setText("Test");
}
```

Comment: Show me the complete stack trace

Comment: @LittleTin provide the stack trace... it's every bit as important as your code (and sometimes is even useful without seeing the code).

Comment: make sure this textView exists in this layout R.layout.activity_main <----

Comment: OK. I got it.it is a stupid mistake. And a new question is how can I set another Textview on other layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check is there any `R.id.textView` in your `activity_main.xml`. If your TextView is nested inside another view, you should do something like this:

```
TextView t1=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

There is also a possibility, this `TextView` is inside your fragment and your fragment doesn't exists when you are trying to find this `TextView` by id.

Comment: OK. I got it.it is a stupid mistake. And a new question is how can I set another Textview on other layout

Comment: If you want to set TextView in main_activity.xml layout : TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); is correct, just add this view to your xml file. But if you want to do this inside fragment, you should do this in OnViewCreated fragment overrided method.

Comment: Could you give me a sample code? I learned from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwqzhY5i2rc to change the fragment.

Comment: You have few classes extends Fragment, so if your fragment have TextView in it's layout you should do something like this inside your Fragment class:

 @Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 final TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
 t1.setText("Test");
}

I think this should work.